# Call a view works in iOS 6 but doesn't in iOS 5

Tags: objective-c, ios5, ios6

in my project, on map annotation, `rightCalloutAccessoryView`, I used the following code to connect from `mapView` to another view, here it is

```
RWStation * temp=[[RWStation alloc]init];
            [temp setTitle:obj.title];
            [temp setPhoneNumber:phoneNum];
            [temp setCabInfo:obj.cabInfo];
            [temp setPrice:obj.price];
            [temp setQuality:obj.quality];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:temp animated:YES];
```

on iOS6, there is no problem but in iOS5, it crashed and displayed this error on the console

> Project[61319:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: 'Could not instantiate
>   class named NSLayoutConstraint'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x1809022 0x1184cd6 0x17b1a48 0x17b19b9 0x5714a3 0x57167b 0x571383 0x47116d 0x3171fc 0x317779 0x31799b
>   0x317d11 0x3298fd 0x329aef 0x329dbb 0x32a85f 0x32ae06 0x32aa24 0x63a4
>   0x61cc06 0x280e49 0x280f34 0x2764b54 0x135d509 0x1740803 0x173fd84
>   0x173fc9b 0x16f27d8 0x16f288a 0x250626 0x225d 0x2185) terminate called
>   throwing an exception(lldb)

I don't know what happen, please help me. Thanks so much.

Comment: I did it, unchecked "use autolayout" but it didn't work. I put the breakpoint, when it run to [self.navigationController pushViewController:temp animated:YES]; the application was crashed

Comment: You need to do it in every xib and storyboard in your project.  If you've deleted any xibs from your project, you need to uninstall the app from the simulator or device to be sure those xibs get deleted from the installation.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your storyboard or any other XIB - file have the selection "use autolayout" ticked. Un-tick it to get it to work.

Here is where you un-tick it:

[image]

To see an video of the *disabling event* check 1:50 into this video:

[**Solution to your problem video**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UlIPWyw8jK4)

Comment: I did it, unchecked "use autolayout" but it didn't work. I put the breakpoint, when it run to [self.navigationController pushViewController:temp animated:YES]; the application was crashed

Comment: Is it perhaps possible that you have XIB-file where that box is ticked? Because this is most definitely your problem!

Answer (score 0):

The constrains are only available on iOS 6 and above. The call to `nslayoutconstrain` is available in iOS 6 and later. There are example question all over stack overflow.

Comment: It works now, it's my fault, thanks for helps, and please close this topic.

Comment: No problem. I won't be able to close the topic for you, you need to place an answer yourself and accept it so the topic would be closed.